# Pagination Helper Customizations (styling)

Tags: cakephp, pagination, helper

I'm using the PaginationHelper and in my view I need to set the class for the current page's link to "current number" and I also need to get rid of the | characters before and after the pages.

I can set the overall class but not the current page class using:

`<?php echo $paginator->numbers(array('before'=>'','after'=>'','class'=>'number')); ?>`

So - I need to generate this:

`<div class="pagination">
<a href="#" class="number" title="1">1</a>
<a href="#" class="number" title="2">2</a>
<a href="#" class="number current" title="3">3</a>
<a href="#" class="number" title="4">4</a>
</div> <!-- End .pagination -->`

But what gets generated is this:

`<div class="pagination">
<span class="current">1</span> | <span><a class="number" href="/admin/users/dashboard/page:2">2</a></span> | <span><a class="number" href="/admin/users/dashboard/page:3">3</a></span> | <span><a class="number" href="/admin/users/dashboard/page:4">4</a></span>

</div>`

Is there a simple way to do this??

Ideally I'd like to remove the spans completely but I don't see a way to do that in the api...

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
echo $paginator->numbers(array(
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'tag' => false,
    'class' => 'number'
));
```

[Take a look at the source code](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/paginator-helper/#line-450), it makes it easier to see what options you can set.

Comment: Should be `$this->Paginator` (cake 1.3) unless its set as a template var in controller.